# Weblogic server 12.1.3 not starting an has no error

Tags: weblogic12c

I'm trying to start the weblogic server. The console gives no error, but the server does not start. Below is the server log.

```
> . JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms192m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=500m . WLS
> Start Mode=Development .
> CLASSPATH=C:\ouaf\CCB2403\CCBC2J\CCBC2J\splapp\standalone\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\ouaf\CCB2403\CCBC2J\CCBC2J\splapp\standalone\lib\joda-time-2.3.jar;C:\ouaf\CCB2403\softwares\weblogic\wlserver\samples\server\examples\build\serverclasses;;;;C:\ouaf\CCB2403\softwares\weblogic\wlserver\server\lib\xqrl.jar;;
> ;C:\ouaf\CCB2403\CCBC2J\CCBC2J\splapp\standalone\lib\xalan-mod-2.7.1.jar;C:\ouaf\CCB2403\CCBC2J\CCBC2J\splapp\standalone\lib\serializer-2.7.1.jar
> .
> PATH=C:\app\ssangu\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\apps\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\ADE\bin;C:\Windows\System32;c:\mksnt\bin64;c:\mksnt\bin;c:\mksnt\bin\X11;c:\mksnt\mksnt;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ACTIVE~1\BIN;C:\AIME\BIN;c:\Program
> Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\bin\win64\x86\AMD64;c:\Program
> Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Bin\win64\AMD64;c:\Program
> Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Bin;c:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform
> SDK\Bin\Winnt;c:\PROGRAM FILES\TERATERM;c:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft
> SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Intel\CPP\Compiler80\ia32e\bin;c:\program files
> (x86)\intel\cpp\idbe80\bin;c:\program files
> (x86)\intel\composerxe-2011\redist\intel64\ipp;c:\program files
> (x86)\intel\composerxe-2011\redist\intel64\mkl;C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Intel\ComposerXE-2011\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Intel\ComposerXE-2011\compiler\lib;c:\Program
> Files\WinZip;C:\apps\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\perl\bin;C:\Program
> Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;c:\pdit\Ruby193\bin;c:\pdit\mcollective\bin;C:\ouaf\CCB2403\softwares\java_1.8\bin;
> .
> ***************************************************
> *  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
> *  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
> *  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
> *  console at http:\\hostname:port\console        *
> *************************************************** starting weblogic with Java version: "Starting Weblogic with the following arguments"
> C:\ouaf\CCB2403\SOFTWA~1\java_1.8\bin\java -hotspot   -Xms192m
> -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=500m   -da -Dplatform.home=C:\ouaf\CCB2403\softwares\weblogic\wlserver -Dwls.home=C:\ouaf\CCB2403\softwares\weblogic\wlserver\myserver -Dwli.home=C:\ouaf\CCB2403\softwares\weblogic\wlserver\integration  -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\ouaf\CCB2403\CCBC2J\CCBC2J\splapp\config\java.login.config
> -Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile=C:\ouaf\CCB2403\CCBC2J\CCBC2J\splapp\security\boot.properties
> -Dweblogic.Name=myserver -Dweblogic.system.StoreBootIdentity=true -Djava.security.policy=C:\ouaf\CCB2403\softwares\weblogic\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.policy
> weblogic.Server  Stopping PointBase server... PointBase server
> stopped. You can close this window
```

The log doesn;t show any error except "Stopping PointBase server... PointBase server stopped. You can close this window"

Can anybody help please.

Comment: Did you have a look at the server log ?
Did you enable the RDBMS security store ?

Comment: Could be memory too.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error occurs if we have any spaces in class path, remove spaces from classpath and  make sure have set $SPLEBASE environment before starting weblogic server. In case it fails, create separate domain and deploy your application on it.